# Import data from another table and mapping in xml file

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I am creating c#.net windows form application with sql server. I have to import data into one table from another table but the mapping between two tables are in xml configuration file and it is dynamic it may be changed by user in future. There are more then 100 fields in each table so how to import data with dynamic mapping.

Actually my xml is like

```
<Mapper MapID="3" Name="thridMappingDoc" SrcDB="OPTICS_SQL" gtDB="TargetSAMPLE">
    <Source>
        <OPTICS_SQL.OrderHDR Spk="" Sfk="" SfkRelation="" />
    </Source>
    <Target>
        <TargetSAMPLE.Sales WhereClause="">
            <TargetSAMPLE.Sales.SaleID Src="OPTICS_SQL.OrderHDR.OrderID" Tpk="Tfk="" TfkRelation="" ConstantValue="" Formula="" AlternateValue="" />
            <TargetSAMPLE.Sales.SaleDate Src="OPTICS_SQL.OrderHDR.OrderDate" Tpk="" Tfk="" TfkRelation="" ConstantValue="" Formula="" AlternateValue="" />
        </TargetSAMPLE.Sales>
    </Target>
</Mapper>
```

second xml file

Suppose we have two xml file,one have define source connection string,target connection string and other one xml having define mapping between srcdb and trgt db.

1-  I have to read source connection and target connection. make a connection based on consetting xml file.
Note:- you can also define your connection string in Consetting xml file

2- I have to read second mapper xml file,according to source connection and target connection find first what tables are attached in both src db and targetdb  . ex.- OrderHDR table column OrderId - 101,102,103  please insert first manually in sql.

3- Check this condition which is given in second mapper xml file

Note:  This means OrderHDR table feild OrderID assign to targetdb "TargetSample", table name "Sales" ,column name "SalesID"
Note: Here OPTICS_SQL is source connection string name

4- Insert OrderID all value which you read from src db to targetdb sales table column salesId.
 Please find attachment below. and first see these xml file,i have also attached
sql script.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: An example of what you're working with would be helpful.

Comment: I have described question properly..Please help for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply create the insert statement dinamically whith column names and values parsed from xmlfile:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("xmlfile1.xml");

string databasename = doc.DocumentElement.Name;

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/" + databasename + "/*[starts-with(name(), 'SourceTableName')]"))
{
    string tablename = node.Attributes["targetTable"].Value;
    string Columns = "";
    string Values = "";

    foreach (XmlNode field in node.SelectNodes("Field"))
    {
        Columns += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Columns) ? ", " : "") + field.Attributes["targetField"].Value;
        Values += (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Values) ? ", " : "") + "'" + field.InnerText + "'";
    }

    //Generate insert statement
    string statement = string.Format("Insert Into {0}.{1} ({2}) Values ({3})",
                                    databasename,
                                    tablename,
                                    Columns,
                                    Values);

    Console.WriteLine(statement);
}
```